# Wordpress permalink issue. Cannot setup "login" as permalink . As the url with this permalink giving " page not found" message

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

I am trying to create a page with a permalink “login” (picture 1). If I save my page with this permalink “login” the page is not been found (picture 2). But if I edit the permalink for example as “login1” the page is published properly (picture 3). And working okay.

I am using “Webcraftic Hide login page” for WordPress login so it should not contradict with Wordpress login. Besides I have another WordPress website which is using login as a permalink for one of the page.

Before installing this “Webcraftic Hide login page” plugin that link (siteurl/login) used to take me to the wordpress login path. (“login” used to redirect as “wp-login.php”).After installing this “Webcraftic Hide login page” plugin I have renamed the worpress login path.

I am pretty sure it will do the same thing if I disable that plugin. Can this be the issue. If so how to resolve it.

I need to make the permalink of the page as “login”. How to correct that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: WordPress already has a build-in redirect for `/login`, to send users to the actual URL of the login mask - and that is probably colliding here. See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135021/how-to-turn-off-redirection-from-domain-com-login-to-domain-com-wp-login-php for suggestions on how to disable that redirect.

Comment: Delete the Login page.Then Go to WP Admin > settings > permalinks and Press "Save Changes" without making any changes. And then create again Login page with "login" permalink. Check if this helps...

Comment: deleting and recreating after saving the permalink settings did not change any thing. I Still getting the page not found message. @Vipin

Comment: check if any caching plugin... Then clear the cache... Check after Disabling "Webcraftic Hide login page"...

Comment: Before installing this “Webcraftic Hide login page” plugin that link (siteurl/login) used to take me to the wordpress login path. (“login” used to redirect as “wp-login.php”). I am pretty sure it will do the same thing if I disable that plugin. Can this be the issue. If so how to resolve it

Comment: @04FS the link you referred to is 5 years old. is it still relevant? I am using the latest version of wordpress

Comment: Well at least the behavior of the automatic redirect is still in place, a quick test using a current WP installation proved that.

Comment: seeing picture 3 it seems that you are using "custom template" or any plugin for the layout... could you please confirm: Is the layout coming from custom page template or somewhere  else?

Comment: The login form in picture 3 is integrated via an iframe.  If you look at picture 1 you can see that.  @vipin

Comment: Then I will suggest create a custom page template for the login page...

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it in my wordpress install, added and activated "Webcraftic Hide login page".

I created a page with permalink "login".

It do not redirect to wp-login.php or wp-admin

It do not shows 404 page

No issues found

=======================================================

Also you should be aware that the redirect only applies if there is nothing else at /login.

As soon as e.g. you create a page /login the redirect doesn't apply any more.

=======================================================

In your case, It could be some other plugin or any setting in your installation.

I would suggest you to:
Create a page-template and assign it to your login page:

page-template-login.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Login
*/

get_header();
?>
    <!-- HTML Container -->

    <!-- HTML Container -->
<?php
get_footer();
```

Save it in your theme directory
Then go to your page: in WP Admin > Pages > Your login page 
And change the page template to "My Login"
Save the page

Then Go to: WP Admin > Settings > Permalinks 
And Click "Save Changes" without making changes.